# How to extract string before and after match with dynamic values, using 'Powershell' and 'RegEx'

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to extract parts of a text file using PowerShell and regex. 
The file is built on values starting from "10" and goes on to "50". All values are static except from "50" (can occur many times in a row)
So far I got this:

```
Select-String .\sample.txt -pattern '^40[\s][\s][\s][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][\s][0][1]' -context 19,0
```

This matches my value and extracts the previous 19 lines of text, so far so good. Then I need to extract the lines proceeding the match, until the next "10".
I know that '-context 19,0' will not extract any lines proceeding the match. It is just as far as I got before getting stuck. Any help is appreciated. Here is an example of the file:

```
10
20
21
22   Value
23   Value
24   Value
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32 
33
34
35
36
37
40   1111111111 01      
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value 
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value 
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value 
50   Value 
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value 
10
20
21
22   Value
23   Value
24   Value
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32 
33
34
35
36
37
40   1111111112 01      
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value 
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value 
50   Value                                                                                                                                             
50   Value
```

The output that i want is this:

```
    10
    20
    21
    22   Value
    23   Value
    24   Value
    25
    26
    27
    28
    29
    30
    31
    32 
    33
    34
    35
    36
    37
    40   1111111111 01      
    50   Value                                                                                                                                             
    50   Value 
    50   Value                                                                                                                                             
    50   Value 
    50   Value                                                                                                                                             
    50   Value 
    50   Value 
    50   Value                                                                                                                                             
    50   Value
```

Comment: Can you clarify using your example what output you actually want?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the expected output? Your regex is really inefficient and unmanageable. It can be rewritten as `^40 {3}\d{10} 01`

Comment: Are you just looking to group the file chucks by the 10's? So every time you see a 10 that is a new group?

Comment: Hi Matt, yes if the line starting with 40 matches my horrible written regex.

Comment: `(?ms)^10(?=(?:(?!^10).)*\d{10} 01)(?:(?!^10).)*`

Comment: Why do you only want the first part of the file and not the second part?

Comment: Thanks a lot ctwheels, that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/2Us5sw/1)

```
(?ms)^10(?=(?:(?!^10).)*\d{10} 01)(?:(?!^10).)*
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##tZHNaoNQEIX35ymmIHhvacK9M5ofIfgE2XbTpsXam0gxGNTQgvHZrUkgkkU2JR1m8XGYM8NwdsW3K6vM5XnXeaXbuB9akK/ibaXfrFHxQsWRih961mP9@PrZWNOSsfpK9uFVdXk0WgPu24KZiJ6TfO/AMmAwYAiegKfgGXgOMRALYYIIJICEkAlkisD0Fnup/jZCc9kyIP1Zvjny38/wvZ7xgZdTdqsoWiZ1mrlKHRN5onOkmg60LkqXpNmo@PhyaU2N9z4@mduu@wU)

```
$regex = '(?ms)^10(?=(?:(?!^10).)*\d{10} 01)(?:(?!^10).)*'
$str = # Your input here

[regex]::Matches($str, $regex) | foreach-object {$_.Value}
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?ms)` Enabled the flags `m` (multiline - allows `^` and `$` anchors to match each line) and `s` (dotall - allows `.` to match newlines `\n`)
- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `10` Match this literally
- `(?=(?:(?!^10).)*\d{10} 01)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `(?:(?!^10).)*` Tempered greedy token matching any character except where `^10` matches
  - `\d{10}` Matches any digit exactly 10 times
  - Match a literal space character
  - `01` Match this literally
- `(?:(?!^10).)*` Tempered greedy token matching any character except where `^10` matches